# ImGui can't find any definitions

Tags: c++, cmake

OS: Windows10
Editor: VScode
Build: CMake
Compiler: GCC(actually MinGW)
ImGui branch: master (I didn't use the release tag branch), GLFW+OpenGL3 implementations

Here is the situation, I'm rewriting my learnOpenGL project with some more features added to it, like using yaml to do the initialization config. Now I want to add a visual config window when I run my opengl demo, so I could adjust colors or shader options or whatever.

I choose ImGui and followed many tutorials from other sites, when I add ImGui cpp files and compile them into a static library, the imgui_gui.cpp(not only this one) can't find any definitions of functions it contains(nearly all).

Below is the structure of my demo's workspace(simplified):

```
I:.
├───.vscode
├───CMakeLists.txt
├───app
│   ├───CMakeLists.txt
│   └───ImGui_test.cpp
├───bin
├───build
├───config
├───images
├───include
│   ├───glad
│   ├───GLFW
│   ├───glm
│   ├───ImGui
│   │   ├───imconfig.h
│   │   ├───imgui.h
│   │   ├───imgui_impl_glfw.h
│   │   ├───imgui_impl_opengl3.h
│   │   ├───imgui_impl_opengl3_loader.h
│   │   ├───imgui_internal.h
│   │   ├───imstb_rectpack.h
│   │   ├───imstb_textedit.h
│   │   └───imstb_truetype.h
│   ├───KHR
│   ├───myImplement
│   ├───stb_image
│   └───yaml-cpp
├───lib
│   ├───libglfw3.a
│   ├───libimgui.a
│   ├───libmysrc.a
│   └───libyaml-cpp.dll
├───model
├───shader
│   ├───shader_fragment
│   └───shader_vertex
└───src
    ├───CMakeLists.txt
    ├───config.cpp
    ├───glad.c
    ├───shader.cpp
    ├───stb_image.cpp
    └───ImGui
        ├───imgui.cpp
        ├───imgui_demo.cpp
        ├───imgui_draw.cpp
        ├───imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
        ├───imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp
        └───imgui_widgets.cpp
```

The problem is, when I compile other opengl demos, this build system works fine, all static and dynamic libraries can be found and linked properly(glfw, yaml, opengl32, and the lib made of cpp files from the 'src' dir except for the cpp files in the 'ImGui' dir), but adding libimgui.a seems not providing correct definitions for demos that contains any imgui function.

```
// a piece of error in cmd
// undefined reference of imgui.cpp(part of)
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:2557: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableEndRow(ImGuiTable*)'
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui.cpp.obj): In function `ImGuiListClipper::Begin(int, float)':
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:2595: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableEndRow(ImGuiTable*)'
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui.cpp.obj): In function `ImGuiListClipper::Step()':
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:2652: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableEndRow(ImGuiTable*)'
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui.cpp.obj): In function `ImGui::GcCompactTransientMiscBuffers()':
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:3357: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableGcCompactSettings()'
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui.cpp.obj): In function `ImGui::NewFrame()':
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:4516: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableGcCompactTransientBuffers(ImGuiTable*)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui.cpp:4519: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableGcCompactTransientBuffers(ImGuiTableTempData*)'
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui.cpp.obj): In function `ImGui::Initialize()':

// undefined reference in imgui_demo.cpp(part of)
../../lib/libimgui.a(imgui_demo.cpp.obj): In function `ShowPlaceholderObject':
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7096: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableNextRow(int, float)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7097: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(int)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7100: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(int)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7116: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableNextRow(int, float)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7117: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(int)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7122: undefined reference to `ImGui::TableSetColumnIndex(int)'
I:/VScode_projects/shader_toy/src/ImGui/imgui_demo.cpp:7128: undefined reference to `ImGui::NextColumn()'
```

Also, three CMakeLists.txt in root directory, src and app:

```
// CMakeLists.txt in root directory
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.19)
PROJECT(shader_toy)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
   LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

SET(GL_LIB opengl32)

OPTION(DEBUG "debug switch" OFF)
OPTION(GEN_SHARED_LIB "generate shared lib .so" OFF)
OPTION(GEN_STATIC_LIB "generate static lib .a" ON)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/app)

//CMakeLists.txt in src directory
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. SRC_LIST)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(ImGui IMGUI_LIST)

IF(DEBUG)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDEBUG)
ENDIF()

IF(SRC_LIST)
    ADD_LIBRARY(mysrc STATIC ${SRC_LIST})
ENDIF()

IF(IMGUI_LIST)
    ADD_LIBRARY(imgui STATIC ${IMGUI_LIST})
ENDIF()

MESSAGE("following source files will be linked into library:")
MESSAGE("------------------- SRC LIST -------------------")

FOREACH(src ${SRC_LIST})
    MESSAGE("${src}")
ENDFOREACH()

MESSAGE("------------------- LIST END -------------------")

// CMakeLists.txt in app directory
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. APP_LIST)

IF (DEBUG)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDEBUG)
    MESSAGE("DEBUG set to ON")
ENDIF()

FILE(GLOB LIB_LIST ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*.dll ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*.a)
IF (LIB_LIST)
    FOREACH (lib ${LIB_LIST})
        MESSAGE("lib found: ${lib}")
    ENDFOREACH ()
ENDIF()

FOREACH (app ${APP_LIST})
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(output ${app} NAME_WE)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${output} ${app})
    IF (LIB_LIST)
        FOREACH (lib ${LIB_LIST})
            GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(lib_name ${lib} NAME_WE)
            GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(lib_post ${lib} LAST_EXT)
            IF (NOT lib_post)
                MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "lib format not recognized\n")
            ENDIF()
            IF (NOT(lib_post STREQUAL ".a" OR lib_post STREQUAL ".so" OR lib_post STREQUAL ".lib" OR lib_post STREQUAL ".dll"))
                MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "lib format not recognized: ${lib_post}\n")
            ENDIF()
            STRING(SUBSTRING ${lib_name} 3 -1 lib_name_without_prefix)
            MESSAGE("${output} will be linked with: ${lib_name_without_prefix}")
            TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${output} ${lib_name_without_prefix})
        ENDFOREACH()
        MESSAGE("${output} will be linked with: ${GL_LIB}")
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${output} ${GL_LIB})
    ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()
```

I know 'undefined reference' is a common linking error in cpp projects, I have fixed many similar problems in my previous cpp projects, but I can't figure out what goes wrong in this one, actually, I have used global search(Ctrl+Shift+f) on these undefined reference functions in VScode, they do don't have formal definitions in any file! All references in search results is the usage or declaration, but no definitions! I don't understand, may be definitions will be generated in compiling???

Will it be the problem in:

1. wrong platform
2. missed steps in compiling / incorrect compile methods
3. wrong OpenGL version(as I don't know which version the opengl32.lib from Windows10 implements)
4. wrong repo, I should download the release tag instead of master branch
5. missing definition files, I forget to copy them into my workspace

If you have used the ImGui library, any advice would be appreciate! Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The above comment looks like someone in review thought the question needed focus- probably due to the list the asker provided about possible causes they considered. In this case, I would consider the list a part of their research effort- that they are aware of different ways the problem could be happening.

Comment: Probably/possibly unrelated note: Please read [the notes in the docs about warning for your usage of `aux_source_directory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/aux_source_directory.html).

Comment: @david-fong, oh, I didn't expect that this question can be viewed by others anymore as it has been put aside for a long time. I viewed your link, and you are completely right, it's the problem of my CMakeLists file, I thought that 'AUX' can recursively grabs all subdirectories, but the fact is that you have to manually specify them. After specifying the imgui subdirectory, the compile process is so smooth, thanks for your comment!

Comment: No problem. I don't quite understand what you mean. Did you find a solution to your problem? If so, post an answer carefully explaining how and mark it as accepted.